# Release memory from loaded xml?

Tags: c#, xml

For example, if you load a xml and use it for whatever reason:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("my.xml");
```

Now that you have finished using it and want to release any memory used by it, initally i tought that setting it to null would do the job but it does not, so what is the proper way to release the used memory if that is possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing the proper thing. Let the GC worry about when it collects as it will when there's pressure.

Comment: What I wanted to know is if it is possible to force it to dispose it or something alike.

Comment: I understand, but you really don't want to mess with that. Let GC do its job - you won't be disappointed :) If my.xml is just too large maybe you can investigate other mechanisms to read&process it which don't involve reading the whole thing at once.

Comment: GC should clean up when it decides it is best to clean up.  Make sure you aren't holding on to a reference to the document somewhere else.

Comment: thanks ... This was the way that it seemed faster to proccess all the data i have tried to stream the data too but this was the faster way but it does not release the load in memory that is not needed until i exit the application that is why i was wondering it.

Comment: @Prix what do you mean stream the data?  Are you using a FileStream and a XDocument?  I'm having the same issue.  I can watch the memory consumption of my app grow by 100MB every time my parse method is called for a new tab.  I isolated the resource allocation to the load/parse method of the XDocument.  It's stored in a local variable for the method however the memory never releases.  How did you end up solving this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is to simple stop using `doc`.  The garbage collector will clean up the memory the next time it's invoked and determines `doc` is no longer referenced by your code.

If `doc` is a local the JIT will determine the last point it's used and make it eligable for collection at that point.  There is no need to `null` it out.  Raymond Chen has an excellent blog article explaining how this works

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100810-00/?p=13193

Comment: Thanks for the answer what I really wanted to know if there is a way actually dispose of it as soon as I finish using it. Because the amount of data that is being parsed and the amount of memory being used and not released is becoming a problem. When the application is closed it is all released and i dont use doc for all the files they have different nameing for example clients or products.

Comment: @Prix no there is not.  If you see memory growing uncontrollably in your app then there is a memory leak somewhere.  You'll need to attach a profiler to find out what is leaking.

Comment: thanks, it only grows when a new xml is loaded and even tought i do use different naming it nevers releases the memory until i exit the program.